# Add sub-header to Material-UI autocomplete component

Tags: javascript, css, material-ui

How can I add a sub-header to Material-UI's `Autocomplete` component?

Right now i'm doing this:

```
<Autocomplete
        {...props}
        options={options}
        renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label={label} />}
/>
```

[This is what I get](https://imgtr.ee/image/J4ahM) and [this is how I need it to look](https://imgtr.ee/image/J4fqu).

How can I get this result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, you need to use the groupBy props of Autocomplete component.
Something like :

```
<Autocomplete
        {...props}
        options={options}
        groupBy={(option) => option.yourCondition}
        renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label={label} />}
/>
```

The documentation gives you examples : [MUI Doc](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-autocomplete/#grouped)